# Jupyter Notebook ModuleError after Homebrew Upgrade

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, package, homebrew

I have been using Jupyter for some time now and it has worked just fine. I have Jupyter and Python installed via Homebrew. I am running on MacOS.

Yesterday, I ran the command `brew upgrade` and now my Jupyter notebook is unable to find any of the installed python packages. I will use Numpy as the example.

When inside of a Jupyter notebook, I try to do

```
import numpy
```

I get the message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

If, however, I launch python in a terminal window, then I can import Numpy without issue.

I first checked that the package was installed correctly by re-issuing the install command

`brew install numpy`

which outputs:

```
Warning: numpy 1.18.4 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.18.4, run `brew reinstall numpy`
```

I also ran

`pip install numpy`

and got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.18.4)
```

Now, this is where I got confused because I expected the path to point to something like `/usr/local/Cellar/`, so I checked the path inside of the Jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

which outputs:

```
['/Users/kseuro/Dropbox/Dev/',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.1.2/libexec/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.1.2/libexec/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.1.2/libexec/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8',
 '',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.1.2/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/2.1.2/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/kseuro/.ipython']
```

Ok, so Homebrew wants Jupyter to use Python3.8? So I tried `brew switch python 3.8` and got:

```
Error: python does not have a version "3.8" in the Cellar.
python's installed versions: 3.7.7
```

I feel like I'm out of my depth now and need help figuring out what to do next. I don't want to start by just changing paths around.

Suggestions? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured out what to do — posting the solution for my future self and others who may stumble upon this.

Since Jupyerlab is in its own Cellar, the Python packages need to end up in the

`/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/x.y.z/libexec/lib/python3.x/site-packages`

directory, where `x, y, z` are integers, so that the Jupyter kernel can find them.

You can do this by calling:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install 'package-name'
```

inside of the Jupyer notebook.

All is well, again.

Comment: YOU LITERALLY SAVED MY DAY! THAAAAANKS

Comment: Yeah, I owe you ... lots. Nothing worse than knowing what the problem is (different paths) but still not knowing what to do about it. Cheers!

Comment: Ta for leaving the answer here! One alternative is just to not use Brew's Jupyter and let Python install it (you can still use Brew's Python). I'm sure there are downsides to this I have not discovered but seemed to solve the problem in a more upstream way for me.